# Why is the right-click menu in the wrong place in the chrome extension options ui?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a google chrome extension, using the new options page (declared in the manifest as "options_ui"). In the last week or so, I started seeing this issue:

When I right-click in the options page, the context menu appears far to the right of where I clicked. In addition, the dropdown list of a `<select>` element also appears far to the right, rather than under the select element where it should go.

I have reproduced this issue on different machines, with different chrome accounts. I tried it out with a bare-bones extension just to make sure. Here is my manifest:

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "check out options page bug",
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
}
}
```

And my options.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
        <option>three</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: I can't see any issue with your code, it looks good on my end http://i.stack.imgur.com/dAZgc.png (see attached image). Is this your intended output?

Comment: I can reproduce - this is definitely a bug. This needs to be filed at https://crbug.com/new - and you already have a good minimal example. Please post an answer here afterwards with a link to the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I reported the issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596494

Comment: @abielita that is my intended output. The problem occurs when you right-click on the options page. The context menu doesn't appear where you clicked. Also, the dropdown menu doesn't appear under the <select> element as it should. However, I noticed that changing the size of the browser in any way temporarily resolves the issue, until the options page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome appears to have resolved this issue.